# Rails 4: Using an exception handler module in API controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I am trying to use an exception handler in my controller but it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
class API::PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_client

    def index
        @foo = @client.foo
    end

    ...

    def set_client

      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
        render json: e.message, status: :not_found
      end

      @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    end
end
```

and when I go to `localhost:3000/clients/[invalid_id]/payments`, I still see the error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Client with 'id'=1):
>   app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:58:in `set_client'

when I'd expect the `RecordNotFound` handler to handle this exception.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rescue block comes after the failure.

```
def set_client
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => err
  render json: { message: err.message}, status: :not_found
end
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I also added an unnecessary `end` after the rescue